# How to unmount a USB flash drive (that is shared over SAMBA) without having to turn off SAMBA first?

Tags: mount, filesystem, samba, usb-drive

I have a USB drive that is shared over the network via a SAMBA share. This is because the contents are to be managed by a remote user.

Now, there is a local user with physical access to the USB drive. Once the remote user has finished "managing" the USB drive, he instructs the local user to unmount the drive for safekeeping.

However, since the USB flash drive is currently being shared over SAMBA, the unmount operation cannot succeed without the SAMBA process first releasing the USB drive's file system. This is undesirable because stopping SAMBA would affect the many other users using the other SAMBA shares.

Is there any way to circumvent this problem? Or am I doing it wrong in the first place? Or what if the local user just pulls out the USB drive anyway? Will this cause any problems?

Answer (score 1):

If your local user is 100% sure that there is no program keeping any file open on this drive anymore it is the `sync` command to write data from buffers (if any) to the drive. Then you can unplug the USB flash drive. 
From DESCRIPTION
 `sync` writes any data buffered in memory out to disk.  This can
include (but is not limited to) modified superblocks, modified inodes,
and delayed reads and writes.  This must be implemented by the kernel;
The `sync` program does nothing but exercise the `sync` system call.

The kernel keeps data in memory to avoid doing (relatively slow) disk
reads and writes.  This improves performance, but if the computer
crashes, data may be lost or the file system corrupted as a result.
The `sync` command ensures everything in memory is written to disk.

Any arguments are ignored, except for a lone `--help` or `--version`
(*note Common options::).

An exit status of zero indicates success, and a nonzero value
indicates failure.